# Converting lots of files from xls to xlsx with Microsoft Compatibility Pack

Tags: c#, excel

I was looking for a way to convert a huge number of files from xls to xlsx programatically , and I actually found a way which did not require pay-to-use libraries - the Microsoft Compatibility Pack.

```
Process.Start(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excelcnv.exe", string.Format(@" -nme -oice {0} {1}", filename, destinationFilename))
```

However, I encountered an issue while converting a huge number of files basically I was iterating over a list of filepaths and running this code, eventually I ended up creating a process for every file I wanted to convert and almost killed my machine.  Can I somehow use one process for a number of files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can process files sequentially. Start a new process for every file, but wait until the processing is done before starting a new process for the next file.

```
var convertProcess = 
    Process.Start(@"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excelcnv.exe",
                  string.Format(@" -nme -oice {0} {1}", filename, destinationFilename));
convertProcess.WaitForExit();
```